# select all checkbox in nested datalists

Tags: asp.net, selectall, nested-datalist

I have a nested datalist structure and want to put select all checkboxes on every cathegories.

the top checkbox works fine but dont know how to do it for per main cathegory

[image]

this works fine:

```
 protected void cbTamaminiSec_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cbTemp;

    foreach (DataListItem ItemP in parentDataList.Items)
    {
        cbTemp = (CheckBox)parentDataList.Items[ItemP.ItemIndex].FindControl("cbTumunuSec");
        cbTemp.Checked = cbTamaminiSec.Checked;

        DataList nestedDataList = (DataList)parentDataList.Items[ItemP.ItemIndex].FindControl("nestedDataList");

        foreach (DataListItem Item in nestedDataList.Items)
        {
            cbTemp = (CheckBox)nestedDataList.Items[Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("cbTamam");

            cbTemp.Checked = cbTamaminiSec.Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

but don't know about partially select (below codes for the chechboxes in the parentdatalist) I put selected id as "0" to emphasize the problem

```
  protected void cbTumunuSec_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selected = 0;//= (int)parentDataList.SelectedItem.ToString(); // problem is here..

        DataList nestedDataList = (DataList)parentDataList.Items[selected].FindControl("nestedDataList");

        foreach (DataListItem Item in nestedDataList.Items)
        {
            CheckBox cbTemp = (CheckBox)nestedDataList.Items[Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("cbTamam");

            cbTemp.Checked = true;

        }
    }
```

what is the solution

Comment: When do you run the last code? Can you run it when the check box is changed? Did you consider doing it with jquery?

Comment: yes when checkboxes are changed

Comment: You can find the container of the checkbox which has the nested datalist via the DataItemContainer property. sender is the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved! 
asp code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenBaslikId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("baslikId") %>' />
```

code behind:

```
protected void cbTumunuSec_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    CheckBox checkAll = (CheckBox)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)checkAll.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField HiddenID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hiddenBaslikId");

    int selected = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenID.Value)-1;

        DataList nestedDataList = (DataList)parentDataList.Items[selected].FindControl("nestedDataList");

        foreach (DataListItem Item in nestedDataList.Items)
        {
            CheckBox cbTemp = (CheckBox)nestedDataList.Items[Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("cbTamam");

            cbTemp.Checked = true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on `OfType LINQ Operator` and `Controls propery`

```
var allControls = nestedDataList.Items[index].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

....//Filter with `Where Operator`
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.control.controls(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: thanks for reply. maybe from parentDataList? because I can get nesteddatalist's item index easyly but parentDatalist not possible

Comment: i'am happy to help you,, you can also

Comment: but my problem is exactly about finding index. where can I find that index?
var allControls = parentDatalist.Items[index].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

Comment: You can pass index in your checkbox properties for example, and get this index in sender argument of delefate,,,Or you can get index by using ItemCommand